# How to find path of eclipse from within an ant file running in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have an Ant script I use to build a software release. We also have a deploy Ant-script that we distribute with the software. On the development machines everybody has Ant, so for now this solution would was fine.

My question has two parts:

1. Would it be feasible to distribute Ant with the deploy script as a simple binary, so people would not have to have the JDK installed?
2. This is the title question: how can I find the Eclipse path from within Ant? (Since Ant is run from the Eclipse bin folder, I thought I should copy that) I tried finding anything like this, but could not locate a reference.

Now, while I admit that best practices might be different, I find this an interesting excercise and it would fix our immediate problem. I would not recommend this as standard practice any day.

Comment: looks like you could use an installer

Comment: of course we could use an installer, as the question states, this is not about best practices or a long term solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I am afraid you need java to run Ant, so you can't distribute it as a binary without including the JRE I guess
2. I've generated a simple build.xml using eclipse and guess what. There's a variable for that

[image]

It seems you can reference it like this

```
<target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </unzip>
</target>
```

Comment: Yes, of course! Thank you. I had read about this sometime but was unable to find it googling.